# spaceport.sys is corrupt - windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I just restarted my laptop, and it's not booting. It boots well, and then it starts checking for disk repair, and then it brings some odd blue screen claiming I select a user account and the log in, but once I do that, it starts diagnosis and then it opens a page, saying autorepair couldn't solve the problem, and it has options for shutting down and advanced, also it points it's worth checking

> D:\windows\system32\logfiles\srt\srttrail.txt

Which shows that

> D:\windows\system32\drivers\spapeport.src is corrupt

Any ideas how I can fix the problem without loosing my files, can I restore the system to three days ago, and still have my files?

Comment: You have a corrupt system file, that is required to boot Windows, this is typically a sign the storage device has started to fail.  **I have never encountered a corrupt system in over 30 years file on a healthy working properly functioning storage device.**  If you have a system restore point you might have luck, but in all my years of fixing problems like this, I have never been able to fix system corrupt within WinSxS outside of Windows.  The system repair that failed would have resolved this problem, which is a sign, it cannot be solved due to the failed device.

Comment: I've tried resetting the PC, but the process failed in the middle because of an error and it undid everything, and I'm starting to get the feeling it might be the storage device that has failed. Does this mean there might be an error with the copy of windows file that is used to reset PC and getting a new windows installation file might solve the problem or I just buy a new hard disk

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the recent updates and did a recent and it fixed the problem.

Comment: You uninstalled a cumlative update or rolled back the installation of a feature update? Simply uninstalling a cumlative update shouldn't have fixed your problem.